# Understanding how to correctly access properties of generic types using keyof

Tags: typescript

Why does the following error:

```js
type DummyArrayGen<P extends 0 | 1> = P extends 1 ? [a:number] : [a:string]

// works as expected
const works =
  ()=><T extends 
    | { A: DummyArrayGen<0>, K: keyof DummyArrayGen<0> } 
    | { A: DummyArrayGen<1>, K: keyof DummyArrayGen<1> }
  >(arr: T['A'], key: T['K'], value: T['A'][T['K']])=>arr[key]=value

// however the following errors - why?
const doesntWork = <
  RArray = DummyArrayGen<0>,
  EArray = DummyArrayGen<1>
>
  ()=><S extends 
    | { A: RArray, K: keyof RArray } 
    | { A: EArray, K: keyof EArray }
  >(arr: S['A'], key: S['K'], value: S['A'][S['K']])=>arr[key]=value
```

[code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAIgrgWwSAggJzQQxAcQgOwB4AFKCAD2AIBMBnKABigB8oBGAPigF4pSKq+OuygB+KAG1MALnyIARhDQBdKNMkzawNAEt8Ac2UAoIwHpTUAO4B7NAGt6mehUgBjKtSOvr+LVdsOPEZQUAAUAJTcHIQAKmSUNPTBISxQAN5QKOrwSKgY2HhEDBwANFAA0up2ECDWAGawiMjoWLgEhMVQAL5QySGsGVmNuS0F7ZxllVDVtQ05zfltRJzdyRyhmBjqMRIA5Ci7ymUz23vlh2UAbpgANnAQp-uHEju758rKkRybaBIzytxrncICZzFAABbWSwQS5KKDAcHQOrWG43KF6fRkDC2egAWis4JAoi8Pj81GsEFo+GAAHUAjwoIRkgAlUYgBnzPKtQodUrJACibI5TS5Y2WHCMEpCESihAAyvFBMI+qlBupWYtJlUavUoBrWt1eilVZl1ILNRVtbMoOaDV01hstlA5XsDkdpjV1C63hcoED7l7Xc9ve9PlEfn8agD-SCgA)

Probably a really simple solution, so I apologise in advance if I'm just being dumb.

Comment: The reason the first one works is because `keyof DummyArrayGen<0>` is a concrete type, and is equal to `keyof DummyArrayGen<1>`. The second one doesn't work because `keyof RArray` and `keyof EArray` may be unrelated to each other, so `S['A']` could be a union of two types with no common keys, and a union is not generally indexable by the union of its constituents' keys. As for how to fix it, the solution is probably to use overloads rather than the generic `S` type, but it's not totally clear what your requirements are.